# HTML table horizontal sizing issue

Tags: html, html-table, scrollbar

I'm sure this is an easy problem to solve, but I'm just not much of a html/css wizard yet!

I have a table that I generate and the spec calls for there being a fixed header while allowing the body to be scrollable.

The problem is, now the horizontal direction is scrollable also, which I don't want it to be. There is no reason it can't be fixed. It looks like the presence of the scroll bar for the vertical direction takes up space so that the browser now thinks that it needs a horizontal scroll to fit in the horizontal content. Frustrating!

Here is what I have so far:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" bordercolor="cccccc">
        <thead style="position:relative;">
            <tr bgcolor="eeeeee">
                <td>Column 1 Header</td>
                <td>Column 2 Header</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;height:480px;">
            <tr>
                <td>Some data</td>
                <td>Some more data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some data</td>
                <td>Some more data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some data</td>
                <td>Some more data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some data</td>
                <td>Some more data</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code? Generally scrolling is displayed based on the size of the container - the element (like <div>) that holds this table. 

It is possible to have only vertical scrollbar without a horizontal one.

Comment: @Nivas - That's everything - the vertical scrolling is accomplished by fixing the height of the body, in this case to 480px. Let me add, I dynamically generate the body contents, so there are actually several hundred rows in my table.

Comment: Don't use these deprecated attributes: cellspacing, cellpadding, border, bordercolor. There exist CSS alternatives for all of them.

Comment: You're right...I'm hacking on old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tau, Check out [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net).  It's a Jquery plugin that reformats your tables via JS and allows for sorting, paging, etc.  The header "freeze" is exactly the functionality that would solve your problems, and the extra features are just bonus.  I've stopped using the "freeze" method and switched nearly entirely to paged tables, which are just a single line of configuration to enable.  Personally, I don't deploy tabular data without it anymore, and the extra 5 lines of code only takes me a minute or two to add.  It's a win-win in my book, no crazy CSS or reformatting required.

Comment: While that looks like a great solution, is there a way I can accomplish what I'm trying to without resorting to this?

Comment: Could we see the container div, etc?  I suspect that is what's causing the horizontal scrolling.  Having done this before, I can tell you it's frustrating because of browser variances and IE's box model issues.  Datatables bypasses all of that.  And, from a UI standpoint, paging trumps scrolling on long tables such as yours.

Comment: There's no surrounding div etc. I just pulled it up in a different browser and there was no scrolling whatsoever in either direction, so I'm going to go ahead and check your solution as the one to go with.